# SyntaxHighlighter gets parsed incorrectly

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

My SyntaxHighlighter gets parsed incorrectly, inserting code blocks with `<pre class="brush: lang">...</pre>` into Markdown, for instance：

**Case 1: remove `</body>`**

```
`</body>` parse as ``
```

**Case 2: incorrectly pairing**

```
<pre class="brush: java">
private class MaxPropComparator implements Comparator<message> {
    ...
}
</pre>
```

is parsed as (add `</message>`):

```
<pre class="brush: java">
private class MaxPropComparator implements Comparator<message> {
    ...
}
</message></pre>
```

**Case 3: embedded code blocks**

```
<pre class="brush: xml; smart-tabs: false">
<pre class="brush: js; highlight: [2, 4, 6]">
...
</pre>
</pre>
```

is parsed as:

```
<pre class="brush: xml; smart-tabs: false">
</pre><pre class="brush: js; highlight: [2, 4, 6]">
...
</pre>
```

therefore display as:

[image]

**Case 4: and so on**

```
# messages: event-type org-node (loc-x,loc-y) (anchor-x,anchor-y) r=<core> a=<availability> ttl size [node-snd ( loc-x loc-y ) [node-rcv (     loc-x loc-y)]]
```

is parsed as (add `</availability></core>`):

```
# messages: event-type org-node (loc-x,loc-y) (anchor-x,anchor-y) r=<core> a=<availability> ttl size [node-snd ( loc-x loc-y ) [node-rcv (     loc-x loc-y)]]
</availability></core>
```

Comment: SyntaxHighlighter renders on the client side, while markdown is usually done at the server side in order to properly render HTML, are you sending markdown to the browser?

Comment: @Capilé I believe the server sends HTML to the browser. I use `jp-markdown` and don't change the core codes of WordPress.

Comment: Hmm, you need another markdown plugin, jetpack is no longer supported, otherwise you'll need to escape manually these tags -- is installing another markdown parser am option for you?

Comment: @Capilé actually, it is not related to markdown plugins, but syntax highlighting. I shift `SyntaxHighligter` to `Google Code Prettify` and it workds perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The reason:**

> PROBLEMS: Major issue with this method is that all left angle brackets must be HTML escaped, eg all `<` must be replaced with `&lt;` This will ensure correct rendering.

---

**My soluation:** shift `SyntaxHighlighter` to `Google Code Prettify` and make the previous codes compatiable with `Google Code Prettify`. Here is what I do:

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('pre').each(function(){
        var el = jQuery(this).find('code');
        var code_block = el.html(); // remove the pairwise tag of <code></code>
        var lang = el.attr('class');

        if (el.length > 0) { // <pre>...</pre> with <code>...</code> inside
            if (lang) {
                jQuery(this).addClass('prettyprint linenums lang-' + lang).html(code_block);
            } else {
                jQuery(this).addClass('prettyprint linenums').html(code_block);
            }
        } else { // <pre>...</pre> without <code>...</code> inside
            jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass('prettyprint linenums'); // take over SyntaxHighlighter
        }
    });
});
</script>
```